# Крестики нолики js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Решил я сделать крестики нолики, но вышла проблема.
Когда нажимаю на клеточку появляется X только в первой клеточке, на какую бы не нажать, все равно только в первой. Похоже событие везде наложено и проблема не в этом.
Спасибо большое кто поможет.

```js
let oneclick = true;

function CreateX() {

  if (oneclick == true) {

    let x = document.createElement("span");
    x.innerHTML = "X";
    x.className = "X";
    document.getElementById("box").append(x);
  }
  oneclick = true

}
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: black 1px double;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.cell:hover {
  border: 1px double red;
}

.X {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="user-select: none;">
  Крестики нолики
</h1>
<div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX()"><span class="X">X</span></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let oneclick = true;

function CreateX(cell) {
  if (!cell.textContent) {
    let x = document.createElement("span");
    x.innerHTML = oneclick? "X" : "O";
    x.className = oneclick? "X" : "O";
    cell.append(x);
  }
  oneclick = !oneclick;
}
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: black 1px double;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.cell:hover {
  border: 1px double red;
}

.X, .O {
  font-size: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<h1 style="user-select: none;">
  Крестики нолики
</h1>
<div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>
  <div class="cell" id="box" onclick="CreateX(this)"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: cell is undefined

Comment: Я давно пробывал через cell тоже самое всегда пишет

Comment: @Half Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.